# Does the API expose the ability to use multiple network interfaces simultaneously?

Tags: applications, networking

I'd like to know if it's possible for an Android application to transfer data via WiFi and mobile simultaneously, or any other network interface such as USB or Bluetooth tethering, *without* requiring root privileges.

Enabling WiFi appears to disable the mobile data connection, but I want to know if this can be overridden using only the API. I'm only interested in individual applications doing this, such as the possibility of multihoming-capable VoIP or Bittorrent clients, or other peer-to-peer applications, in order to aggregate throughput capacity, improve reliability, and enable seamless handover. All ordinary ‘naïve’ applications should behave as they do currently.

Comment: I recently asked a dev about what could be done with the `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` permission. His investigation brought the surprise an app can define routes with that, so it could enforce routing data to a specific IP via 3G while WiFi is on – at least theoretically.

Comment: @Izzy: Brilliant, thanks! Provided that mobile data is still connected even though the indicator disappears, the ability to define routes via the API probably means that the answer is yes! I may be able to verify that and answer the question myself, but I'll investigate further tomorrow. :-)

Comment: Please keep us updated. I didn't post it as answer as I cannot verify. If you can prove it works, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Tried to prove by demonstration using BeanShell for SL4A to avoid making a dummy app just to answer the question, whilst retaining direct access to the API. Found out that it's a myth that BeanShell has access to the whole API due to the lack of a `Context`. [See my Q/A about it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038611/how-do-i-obtain-the-android-context-in-beanshell-for-sl4a) Unfortunately that includes [`requestRouteToHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestRouteToHost%28int,%20int%29), making my investigation so far fruitless… :-(